# flutter record: How do I make the audio recording in an application record more than a minute?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I make the audio recording in an application record more than a minute?

[image: code]

Comment: what is the error if you put the timer on more than 60?

Comment: i want more than 60s

Comment: what happens when you set the timer more than 60s?